# Bundling and Minification without using tools in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2 web application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Do we have any way to implement Bundling and Minification without using any tools like Grunt, Gulp, WebOptimizer etc. in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2 web application similar to ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Nope. The ASP.NET MVC approach was junk, anyways.

Comment: How about using Web Compiler and Bundler & Minifier by Mads Kristensen?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET supports bundling and minification out of the box, but same is not true for ASP.NET Core.

If you intend for css and javascript files, ASP.NET Core comes with a built in `BundlerMinifier`.In ASP.NET Core 2.1 or later, add a new JSON file, named `bundleconfig.json`, to the MVC or Razor Pages project root like this

```
[
{
  "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
  "inputFiles": [
    "~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "~/css/*.css"
  ]
},
{
  "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
  "inputFiles": [
    "~/js/*.js"
  ],
  "minify": {
    "enabled": true,
    "renameLocals": true
  },
  "sourceMap": false
}
]
```

Refer to [Bundle and minify static assets in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#configure-bundling-and-minification)

Comment: BundlerMinifier is full of bugs, it can't even minimize the file properly. this is an example of how it minimized my property names and not working

function createToppingGroupOrders(n) {
    var u = [], r, t, f, i;
    for (let n of n) {
        r = {};

As you can see it puts n everywhere and js doesn't now hot wor run it and getting error